# "filling" areas based on mask from other image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have the following problem with a minimal example:

I have an two images of the same size (see below) - one shows diffrent ellipses and the other shows regions of interest within some of those ellipses. What I want now is to color the ellipses that contain those regions red and those that don't contain those blue, or use some other labeling separating those types of ellipses.
For this I already tried using connectedComponents with partial sucess:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

example = cv.imread('example.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
roi = cv.imread('roi.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

_, comp = cv.connectedComponents(example)

# get list of labels where the roi is present
redmarks = np.unique(comp[roi != 0])

# components with labels mentioned above are red otherwise blue
redmask = np.isin(comp, redmarks)
bluemask = np.invert(redmask) & comp > 0

result = cv.cvtColor(example, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
result[redmask] = [0, 0, 255]
result[bluemask] = [255, 0, 0]

cv.imshow("Test", result)
k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

Now there are three questions:

1. For the bluemask for some reason two ellipses are missed. The two parts of the logic - inverted redmask and not being the black background label 0 -  individualy include both parts, so both should be present. Am I missing something?
2. Is there potentially a better and faster way to achieve what I want? There may be a build-in method that does, what I`m trying to do, that I have not encountered yet, as I'm fairly new to OpenCV.
3. In the end I also want to assess whether this particle is "for reals" red or not, e.g. if a roi is very small in comparison to the whole associated ellipse it shall not be labeled with red. I haven't thought about it much yet, as I want the basic thing to work properly and I already feel that my implementation would be slow as hell. So if you have any ideas regarding this, I would be very happy.

Thanks!
example.png:
[image: example.png]
roi.png
[image: roi.png]
Overlapped:
[image]
Current result:
[image: result]

Edit:
Alright, I have a solution for 3.:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':

    example = cv.imread('example.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    roi = cv.imread('roi.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    result = np.zeros((example.shape[0], example.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    count, comp = cv.connectedComponents(example)

    for c in range(1, count+1):
        # mask of c-connected component
        mask = np.zeros(example.shape, np.uint8)
        mask[comp == c] = 1

        # average of roi in this mask
        mn, _, _, _ = cv.mean(roi, mask=mask)

        # everything over 20% shared area red, else blue
        pr = 20
        if mn > 255*pr/100:
            result[comp == c] = [0, 0, 255]
        else:
            result[comp == c] = [255, 0, 0]

    cv.imshow("Test", result)
    k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

**BUT** the problem of 2. is as expected pretty big for this solution. While for this example it is as fast as the other code without respect towards area, it is **much** slower for examples with larger resolution and amount of components (can`t/won't share this example).
Is there a way to optimize the code inside the for-loop?

Comment: **OpenCV** expects channels in **BGR** order not **RGB**... `cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Oh right. But funnily enough it hasn't changed a thing.

Comment: Alternativaly using `result = np.zeros((example.shape[0], example.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)` without conversion to BRG yields the same result, without the white ellipses of course.

Comment: Ok, problem 1. is solved, by using np.logical_and, no idea why operator & doesn't work. 2. and 3. are still open.